# React Native TouchableHighlight ignores the first click event

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using TouchableHighlight for making buttons, but it seems the first click event on the button does not trigger the `onPress` event on the TouchableHighlight element. It works when it is clicked again.

The code looks like:

```
 return (
  <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={this.props.onPress}
      style={btnStyles}
      underlayColor="#a30000"
      activeOpacity={1}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.children}</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
```

This is the link to the button I created: https://github.com/uiheros/react-native-redux-todo-list/blob/master/app/components/shared/Button.js

Does anyone know how to fix it? or what caused the problem?

Edit: currently the problem happens to me on both ios simulator and android simulator. I have not tested in real devices yet.

Comment: Your code works perfectly on Android device.

Comment: Thanks Jickson for testing it on Android device.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using an emulator to test the app (genymotion?) same thing happened to me and I got confused but rest assured that the issue is not with you app but emulator or operation system(sometimes the first click is just to bring the emulator into focus) I am positive that if you try it on the physical device it'll work properly.

Hope I was helpful

Comment: Thanks Ronak, was about to embark on a long and painful journey to fix this... you are correct!  First thing to do when confronted with a painful and confusing problem - check if it's the emulator!