# React Native TouchableHighlight in Listview ignores the first click event

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-listview

I have this issue in both iOS Simulator and in real device too.
I have a Listview with Touchablehighlight. When i press the list at first, it ignores. It only functions when it is double clicked.Can anyone help me out with this.
Here i have a piece of code, that is inside my render function

```
 <ListView dataSource= {ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.searchedAdresses)}
            renderRow={this.renderAdress} 
            renderSeparator={this._renderSeperator}
            enableEmptySections={true}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          />



renderAdress = (rowData, sectionID, rowID) => {
return (
<TouchableHighlight onPress = {this._onPressAddressList.bind(this,rowData.place_id,rowData.description)}underlayColor = '#a9a9a9' >
<View shouldRasterizeIOS={true} renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}>
    <Text  style={ styles.listTextInput } >{rowData.description</Text>
</View>
</TouchableHighlight>
);};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 cases:

1. You have `TextInput` gaining the focus and when you tap your list view item the first time it removes focus from the input and hides the keyboard. This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543753/react-native-textinput-blur-consumes-touchablehighlight-press-event).
2. They [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670120/react-native-touchablehighlight-ignores-the-first-click-event) that this is an issue with emulator.